# Share a Portable Disk in a Homegroup

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing, homegroup

I have two Windows 7 computers in the same Homegroup and file share is working. My question is that is there any way to share all the disk? In particular, I have some portable disks and my goal is that whenever and wherever the disk is plugged onto, both computers can see it instantly. Is there any way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
right click on the drive in question, and select properties

[image]

Follow the numbers!
Select the Sharing tab

Then

1. Advanced Sharing
2. Share this folder checkbox
3. Set share name
4. Permissions Button (optional)
5. Set Permissions

On the client side, you'll have to select the *location* of the share manually

You can either Select Network, the system in question and the share

[image]

or type in the share name manually in the usual \computername\sharename format

Answer (score -2):

> - Right click Hard Drive (example Drive `D:`)
> - Click share with > Advance sharing.
> - Then click "Share..."
>
> If you want to use Drive D: using another PC or laptop over the network, then proceed with:
>
> - Right click Hard Drive (example Drive `D:`)
> - Click Share with > advance sharing > Security Tab > Edit > Add
> - Then click Advanced... > Find Now > Select "NETWORK" > OK
> - Under Network, tick allow Full Control and Modify > Apply..

— **Source:** [Hard Drive sharing sa Homegroup network(Windows7) Tutorial](http://www.istorya.net/forums/networking-and-internet/380385-hard-drive-sharing-sa-homegroup-network-windows7-tutorial.html)

Comment: Copy paste answers, with no changes to the original post, and no attribution (someone else had to fix it)... Really?

Comment: it's better than just criticize .. Do you have a better answer

Comment: http://superuser.com/faq#deletion <- I'd point that out. I'm also currently working on throwing together an answer with screenshots, once i can get my hands on a USB drive and set up a homegroup. The original answer had bits of *taglog* on it. And no attribution other than it having been googled.

Comment: @ReniataCristiani Having a better answer or not doesn't change the fact that plagiarism (copypasta without attribution) is not encouraged here. Please respect that.